# Dynamic JSON issue

Tags: java, json

My JSON Structure will vary depend on the request. But the content inside each element remain same. For Example:

## JSON1:

```
{
   "h1": {
        "s1":"s2"
   },
   "c1": {
      "t1:""t2"
   }
}
```

## JSON2:

```
{
   "h1": {
        "s1":"s2"
   },
   "c2": {
      "x1:""x2"
   }
}
```

In the above example, elements inside h1,c1 and c2 are constant. Please let me know how to convert JSON to JAVA Object

Regards  
Udhaya

Comment: try using gson api https://github.com/google/gson

Comment: "t1:""t2"  json format incorrect should be "t1":"t2" and "x1": "x2" Instead of "x1:""X2"

Answer (score 0):

First of all You need to understand Json Structure cause above format is incorrect  visit [this](http://jsonlint.com/)

and [this](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/)

And you can use Google Gson or Json for parsing the result json String .

Answer (score 0):

"t1:""t2" json format incorrect

Used

```
"t1":"t2"
```

Instead of

```
 "t1:""t2"
```

and also used

```
"x1": "x2"
```

Instead of

```
 "x1:""X2"
```

> Code to take in java

```
 try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);

            JSONObject jsonsubObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("h1");

            String s1 = jsonsubObject.getString("s2");


            JSONObject jsonsubObject1 = jsonObject.getJSONObject("c1");
            String t1 = jsonsubObject1 .getString("t2");
          }
            catch (JSONException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Google Gson:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
ClassName object;
try {
    object = gson.fromJson(json, ClassName.class);
} catch (com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException ex) {
    //the json wasn't valid json
}

String validJson = gson.toJson(obj);  //obj is an instance of any class
```

`json` must be a valid JSON `String`

Answer (score 0):

import org.json.JSONObject;
you can simple pass your data in constructor of  JSONObject it automatically handle, you need to throws JSONException  which may occur during conversion id format of data is not correct

```
String data = "{'h1':{'s1':'s2'},'c1':{'t1:''t2'}}";
  JSONObject jsnobject = new JSONObject(data);
```